# ASP.NET Core Find All Class Types In All Assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make a modular based .NET core app, and I need to find all classes of a specific type(s) across all assemblies. As each module will be built in it's own project.

But I can't see/find how to do that in ASP.NET Core? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: A few times they changed it in dotnet core. But I remember, they also needed it for the razor compiler you can start looking there. Generally I think it's better for a module to have 1 entry point and let it itself define it's other classes. Instead of auto-magic reflection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To load all classes from one assembly please see below code. In My case `IProfile` is the interface which I need to Search

```
var all = Assembly
        .GetEntryAssembly()
        .GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(Assembly.Load)
        .SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
        .Where(type => typeof(IProfile).IsAssignableFrom(type));    

foreach (var ti in all)
{
   var t = ti.AsType();
   if (t.Equals(typeof(IProfile)))
   {

   }
}
```

Hi [leen3o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82197/leen3o), In case you have external assemblies or Plugins, You can get all types by iterating from the list of assemblies. 
In below code "GlobalConfiguration.Modules" holds my list of plugins

```
List<Type> typeToRegisters = new List<Type>();  
    foreach (var module in GlobalConfiguration.Modules)
    {
    typeToRegisters.AddRange(module.Assembly.DefinedTypes.Select(t => t.AsType()));
          }     

    var entity-types = typeToRegisters.Where(x =>  x.GetTypeInfo().IsSubclassOf(typeof(IBaseDomainEntity)) &&  !x.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);
```

here "IBaseDomainEntity" is my Interface I am searching for. The Only thing I am concerned here is the Efficiency that I have not checked

Comment: Thanks for this. But unless I am mistaken, this will only get the executing assembly and any referenced assembly from the executing one? Unfortunately I need to search/get ALL assemblies even if they are not referenced by the executing assembly. As someone could put a plugin dll in the website, and the website would know nothing about it.

Comment: Hi [leen3o](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82197/leen3o) , I hope edited post should give your answer

Comment: I don't think this gets the entry assembly, just the referenced assemblies from the entry assembly.

Answer (score 6):

I probably found a way of achieving this,

```
var all =
        Assembly
        .GetEntryAssembly()
        .GetReferencedAssemblies()
        .Select(Assembly.Load)
        .SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
        .Where(type => typeof(ICloudProvider).IsAssignableFrom(type.AsType()));
foreach (var ti in all)
{
    var t = ti.AsType();
    if (!t.Equals(typeof(ICloudProvider)))
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

I am worried about the cost of the `Assembly.Load` part, but this will probably get my work done for now - as I only need the Fully Qualified Name of all the classes that implements `ICloudProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should get a collection of all the assemblies you want to search, than you can loop through the assemblies to find a possible type match.

The code below shows you how to get an assignable type. You can also add checks to exclude abstract classes or check if a type implements a generic type.

```
foreach (var assembly in _assemblies)
{
    foreach (var candidate in assembly.ExportedTypes.Select(t => t.GetTypeInfo()))
    {
        if (assignTypeFrom.GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(candidate) && candidate.IsClass)
        {
            yield return candidate.AsType();
        }
    }
}
```